# AutoFixture: Can you unfreeze a data type?

Tags: autofixture

Is it possible to unfreeze for an object type after freezing?

So if I have an object Appointment that uses DateTime, is there a way to do something like this?

```
var time = fixture.Freeze<DateTime>();
IEnumerable<ClientAppointment> appointments = fixture.CreateMany < ClientAppointment>();
fixture.Unfreeze<ClientAppointment>();
```

So that I can generate new objects with a different DateTime injected into them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no documented, stable way of unfreezing a type in AutoFixture.

Instead, change the order in which you create objects, so that

```
var time = fixture.Freeze<DateTime>();
IEnumerable<ClientAppointment> appointments = fixture.CreateMany < ClientAppointment>();
```

is the last thing you do.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was just an extremely simplified example I was using to explain what I was trying to do, but thanks. It's good to know that I wasn't just missing things.

Comment: @Riplikash What are you *really* trying to do? Consider describing the actual problem in a new question, and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: It's fine. It's part of a larger test framework, and as happened here I feel it would require too much context. We just have many data generation setup modules, and freeze could simplify some of them. But the effect would also trickle over into other modules and into the final unit test. So for now the rule is, "don't use freeze in a module". 

I was just trying to find a way to use freeze in a module but to isolate the effect to the scope of the module. I don't think a SO question is really an appropriate forum for a discussion like that, but thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @MarkSeemann any update on this? Any new feature plan to support this?

Comment: @JoanComasFdz I can't answer. I've not been involved with the project for years. You might have more success asking at https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture